# Adding tool bar as an Action bar creating additional margin

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm trying to build a layout which is using CollapsingToolbarLayout to perform collapse of Toolbar and allow Recycle View contain to scroll.

**It work great except.**

1. View that I want to hookup on scrolling, and scroll till action bar height.

**What I need:**

1. Scroll Sticky Header with/till it's own size, not action bar size.

Small Snippet from XML i'm using added [**here**](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1eOwncp3XWaZXskLXCqZ-uy4plIUaysRnwngXGQZDNps/edit?usp=sharing).

**What is my observation:**

1. There must be some dependency between CollapsingToolbarLayout and toolbar I'm using as an Action Bar.
2. If use theme with Default Action bar, then everything worked so perfect.

Any suggestion if I'm missing anything!!

[image]

Comment: First of all, why have you posted code as a link, instead of posting it directly in the question? And second I don't think you need both `collapsingtoolbarlayout` as well as `appbarlayout`. Try removing the app bar layout

Comment: Thanks @VivekMishra , but I believe to get scroll behaviour for Recycle view I'll be require AppBarLayout. Can you help with some XML layout example I should follow !!